# Why are Struts2 tags are slower than Struts1 tags

Tags: struts2, struts-1

I've migrated a Struts1 application to Struts2. On the same page, I've timed them for rendering.

Pages with Struts2 tags are rendered at least 100 times slower than in Struts1.

Struts2 is generally slower than Struts1 in rendering pages but given what it has to offer, it's a pretty worthy trade off.

**Question:** 
Why though that Struts2 has to be slower? And is it possible to make it as fast as Struts1.

**Note:**
I've gone through everything listed on the performance tuning site, but none of them helped.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Two main reasons: OGNL isn't that speedy, and FreeMarker is a full-blown templating language. *Specific* issues can be addressed on a page-by-page basis--there's no general reason it should be two orders of magnitude slower, but without any details, it's impossible to say. Comparisons like this require an apples-to-apples comparison, and that's difficult to wedge into a small question. I'd suggest making a simple test page with the two frameworks and attacking it that way.

Comment: Have you tried javatemplates plugin? Can you show your JSP.